# Safely and properly set a progressbar's maximum with a long in Java

Tags: java, int, progress-bar, long-integer

So here is the backstory. I have some code that retrieves the total number of bytes of all the files from a given directory. Once that is done it returns that value as a long. My problem now is that I want to be able to set a progress bar's maximum as that long.

Eventually I want to start copying those files to different directories and update the progress bar accordingly.

```
public static long GetSize(String path) {
    File dir = new File(path);
    File[] fileArr = dir.listFiles();
    long totSize = 0;
    for (int c = 0; c < fileArr.length; c++) {
        totSize += fileArr[c].length();
    }
    return totSize;
}
```

And then

```
progressBar.setMaximum(FileSizeHandling.GetSize(location)); <-- This is invalid
```

What is the most appropriate and safest way to set the progress bar's maximum as that long?

I know there are ways to convert a long to an int safely, however my main concern is that in some circumstances the long's value will be more than the an integers maximum possible value.

or should I scrap that form of thinking entirely and attempt a different approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set the maximum length of your progress bar to 100, then calculate a divisor as follows:

```
long divisor = totalSize / 100;
```

Then each time you want to update the progress bar, simply:

```
int progressAmount = (int)(amountCopied / divisor);
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) I was thinking of things super complex and was getting nowhere. Much appreciated!